# How to give a margin to the first and last instance of markLabel in MUI Slider field?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI's Slider component in my React project like so:

```
<Slider
          id={name}
          aria-label="Restricted values"
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          getAriaValueText={valuetext}
          step={step}
          value={value}
          valueLabelDisplay={valueLabelDisplay}
          marks={options}
          onChange={onChange}
          onClick={triggerValidation || null}
          min={min}
          max={max}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
```

Now it html, the first marksLabel value looks like this:

```
<span aria-hidden="true" data-index="0" class="MuiSlider-markLabel-jynbEM hiERdh MuiSlider-markLabel MuiSlider-markLabelActive" style="left: 0%;">400</span>
```

I want to either change the left: 0% to 3% or give a margin-left and margin-right to the first and last instance of this markLabel.

I have tried this:

```
    .MuiSlider-markLabel {
      color: #a3b2cc;

      &:first-child {
        left: 3% !important;
        margin-left: 20px;
      }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using data-attribute:

```css
.MuiSlider-markLabel[data-index="0"]{
    left: 3% !important;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

For a more detailed explanation, refer to this:
https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-data-attributes/

Comment: Oh that's a nice approach. Thanks for sharing!